# ____ hurts. ____ stinks

Tags: riddle, word

Everyone will do crazy things for me. Change a letter and you lose. What am I?

Hint: everyone has this at one or another in life.

Comment: Is this an original riddle, or did you get it from somewhere else? Also, please read my comment on your [recently deleted question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/109811/what-happens-once-in-a-year-twice-in-a-week-but-never-in-a-month); the riddle should be the in the question body and attribution is always required for non-original riddles.

Comment: I made it up on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Love. Change v to s and you lose.